# use timer in a vb.net dll

Tags: vb.net, dll, timer

I need to wait for and event within a given period (30s) and then timeout if this time elapse. What do I need to do?

Am sending a command to a server from a dll, and i need to wait for response before sending another. I want to implement a timeout feature, that why i need to use a timer

I want to use a timer, but don't know how to use it in a DLL.

Comment: A timer is a timer. What does it matter whether it's in a DLL or not? Could you give us some more details as to how the pieces of your app fit together because at the moment I can't see what your problem is.

Comment: @David Heffernan Am sending a command to a server from a dll, and i need to wait for response before sending another. I want to implement a timeout feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little piece of code illustrates why using a timer to represent an interval of time is generally a bad idea

```
Dim WithEvents myTimer As New Windows.Forms.Timer 'a timer
Dim stpw As New Stopwatch
Dim count As Long

Const intervalValue As Integer = 1000 'some number of ms. s/b > 10

Private Sub myTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, _
                         ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles myTimer.Tick
    count += 1
    Dim foo As Long = count * intervalValue 'the interval using tick firing every intervalValue ms.
    Dim bar As Long = stpw.ElapsedMilliseconds 'the actual amount of time that has passed

    Label1.Text = foo.ToString("n0")
    Label2.Text = bar.ToString("n0")

    Label3.Text = (bar - foo).ToString("n0") 'show error
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, _
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown

    myTimer.Interval = intervalValue 'number of ms.
    myTimer.Start()
    stpw.Start()

End Sub
```

A better approach is to set the timer to some smaller value, say one second for your example, and see if the elapsed time is greater than the value you are looking for.

Comment: am connecting to an smtp server in order to send mail, how do i wait for response without freezing the UI in class library

Comment: Rather than trying to figure out what the code you've shown is supposed to mean, can you just tell me? Are you saying that a `Timer` does not have a guaranteed resolution, so *more* time might elapse than you expect? Yeah, I thought that was pretty well known. It's not a reason that using a timer control is contraindicated; it's a reason you need to check the values correctly.

Comment: If you are using the SMTP client it has a send async method that will not block.  @cody - yes it is pretty well known.

Answer (score 5):

There are four timers in .NET - `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, `System.Threading.Timer` and `System.Timers.Timer`, and `System.Windows.DispatcherTimer`.

You can use any of them from a class library just as well as from an executable, but you need to choose the most appropriate one to your situation - which isn't very clear.

If you expect to be running within a UI thread, you should use an appropriate UI-based timer; otherwise one of the others. The more information you can give, the more we'll be able to help.